# After upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 6: Current document does not have a doctype

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-material, angular6

I just upgraded my **Angular 5** project to **Angular 6**. After the upgrade it compiles fine, but the website shows up blank. In the console I get:

> Current document does not have a doctype. This may cause some Angular
>   Material components not to behave as expected.
>   push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.MatCommonModule._checkDoctypeIsDefined @   core.es5.js:127
>   MatCommonModule   @   core.es5.js:92
>   _createClass  @   core.js:8116
>   *createProviderInstance$1 @   core.js:8088 initNgModule   @   core.js:8024 NgModuleRef*   @   core.js:8747 createNgModuleRef  @   core.js:8736
>   debugCreateNgModuleRef    @   core.js:10561
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create   @   core.js:11263
>   (anonymous)   @   core.js:4161
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke  @   zone.js:388
>   onInvoke  @   core.js:3671
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke  @   zone.js:387
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @   zone.js:138
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run    @   core.js:3585
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory    @   core.js:4159
>   (anonymous)   @   core.js:4200
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke  @   zone.js:388
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @   zone.js:138
>   (anonymous)   @   zone.js:872
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask  @   zone.js:421
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @   zone.js:188
>   drainMicroTaskQueue   @   zone.js:595 Promise.then (async)
>   scheduleMicroTask @   zone.js:578
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask    @   zone.js:410
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask    @   zone.js:232
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask   @   zone.js:252
>   scheduleResolveOrReject   @   zone.js:862
>   ZoneAwarePromise.then @   zone.js:962
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule   @   core.js:4200
>   ./src/main.ts @   main.ts:12
>   **webpack_require**   @   bootstrap:76 0  @   main.ts:13
>   **webpack_require**   @   bootstrap:76 checkDeferredModules   @   bootstrap:43 webpackJsonpCallback   @   bootstrap:30 (anonymous)
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
>       at MatCommonModule.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js.MatCommonModule._checkThemeIsPresent
>   (core.es5.js:141)
>       at new MatCommonModule (core.es5.js:93)
>       at _createClass (core.js:8116)
>       at *createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:8088)
>       at initNgModule (core.js:8024)
>       at new NgModuleRef* (core.js:8747)
>       at createNgModuleRef (core.js:8736)
>       at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (core.js:10561)
>       at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create
>   (core.js:11263)
>       at core.js:4161

Is this something wrong with `@angular/material`, or did something not upgrade correctly in the project?

If there is anything I can add to help diagnose, let me know.

Comment: Did you check if you declared a doctype in your `index.html`?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I created a new angular 6 project from scratch and added all my files to it. Didn't ever figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove this warning, just add a **Doctype** at the top of your general `index.html` file, like that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
</html>
```